# Laravel file upload path and view rendering

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I successfully upload a file and store its path with the following snippet:

```
/*Image Handling*/
                $file = Input::file('profilePicture');
                $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                Input::file('profilePicture')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                //Profile image
                $profileImg = $destinationPath.$filename;
```

then I store profileImg in database. This is what it looks like:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devproject/public/images/picture.jpeg
```

Now I want to show this picture in one of the views. So I did this:

```
<a class="th" href="{{URL::to('/')}}">{{ HTML::image($details->profileImg, "work", array('style' => 'width:100px;height:100px;')) }}</a>
```

and this is how it is rendered:

```
<a class="th" href="http://localhost:8888/devproject/index.php"><img src="http://localhost:8888/devproject/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devproject/public/images/picture.jpeg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" alt="work"></a>
```

This of course doesn't work because the path is incorrect but it is how it was stored. I need the path to the image to be :

```
/public/images/picture.jpeg
```

instead of this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/devproject/public/images/picture.jpeg
```

as this would fit in the url and show the picture. Any advices on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't save the whole path to the model, save just the filename:

```
$profileImg = $filename;
```

Then, instead of using `$details->profileImg` by itself, use:

```
asset('images/' . $details->profileImg)
```

i.e.:

```
{{ HTML::image('images/' . $details->profileImg, "work", array('style' => 'width:100px;height:100px;')) }}
```